# How to count the number of times an attribute appears in an inner query?

Tags: oracle, join, oracle-11g, group-by

I have this query that I am trying to write out:

> Which students (names) have taken more than one course from the same professor?

I have a students, course, and professor table. This is the ER diagram:

[image]

I have 4 tables:

- `Students` (`student_id` is the PK)
- `Courses` (`course_id` is the PK and `professor_id` is the FK to the Professor Table)
- `Takes_courses` (`student_id` and `course_id` is the PK)
- `Professor` (`professor_id` is the PK)

My plan:

```
Select student_name
From Student
Where student_id > Some (Select *
                         From Courses Natural Join Takes_Courses
                         Group By professor_id)
```

I am not able to run this query above. How am I supposed to count the number of student_id appears in the inner query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testbed:

> ```
> create table students (student_id integer, student_name varchar(100));
> ```

> ```
> insert into students(student_id,student_name)
> select 1, 'Alice' from dual
> union all
> select 2, 'Bob' from dual
> union all
> select 3, 'Charlie' from dual;
> ```

> ```
> create table courses (course_id integer, professor_id integer);
> ```

> ```
> insert into courses
> select 9+level, mod(level,3)+101 from dual connect by level<=10;
> ```

> ```
> create table takes_courses (student_id integer, course_id integer);
> ```

> ```
> insert into takes_courses
> select student_id, course_id
> from students cross join courses
> where course_id<10+student_id*3;
> ```

The query below:

1. Finds all unique student/professor/course combinations (so we don't get results for students who take the same course twice — not sure that is possible from the question).
2. Groups the student/professor pairings and filters out those that only match a single course.
3. Uses the resulting student IDs to look up the student names.

> ```
> select student_name
> from students
> where student_id in ( select student_id
>                       from( select distinct student_id, professor_id, course_id
>                             from takes_courses join courses using(course_id) )
>                       group by student_id, professor_id
>                       having count(*)>1 );
> ```
>
> ```
> | STUDENT_NAME |
> | :----------- |
> | Bob          |
> | Charlie      |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4b2d251ad8aff0c04eb0f72f25c7a8aa)*

Comment: The final answer was similar to what I needed with the nested queries.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this.

The below lists everything: which student took which course  taught by which professor.

```
select
  s.student_id, c.course_id, p.professor_id
from
  students s
  join takes_course tc on (s.student_id = tc.student_id)
  join course c on (c.course_id = tc.course_id)
  join professor p on (p.professor_id = c.professor_id)
;
```

But we do not care about courses. The below lists which student is taught by which professor(s). `(student_id, course_id)` is unique, and 1 course is taught by 1 professor, so the same (student_id, professor_id) values appear multiple times, if the student attended multiple courses taught by the same professor.

```
select
  s.student_id, p.professor_id
from
  students s
  join takes_course tc on (s.student_id = tc.student_id)
  join course c on (c.course_id = tc.course_id)
  join professor p on (p.professor_id = c.professor_id)
;
```

We do not care about professor_id and we need to list students taught by more than 1 course.

```
select
  s.student_id
from
  students s
  join takes_course tc on (s.student_id = tc.student_id)
  join course c on (c.course_id = tc.course_id)
  join professor p on (p.professor_id = c.professor_id)
group by
  s.student_id, p.professor_id
having
  count(*) > 1
;
```

This may list the same student multiple times because a student can take 2 courses from a professor and 3 courses from another professor, so list 1 student only once:

```
select
  distinct s.student_id
from
  students s
  join takes_course tc on (s.student_id = tc.student_id)
  join course c on (c.course_id = tc.course_id)
  join professor p on (p.professor_id = c.professor_id)
group by
  s.student_id, p.professor_id
having
  count(*) > 1
;
```

Comment: (upvoted) The only thing I'd say is: we need the students' names - not the IDs!

Comment: I am confused on how those three join statements work. Does the result of the first join get joined with the result of the second and so on?